# Is there a kashrut issue with vacuum sealers

Tags: kashrut-kosher, technology, modern-times

Food does not directly touch the machine, but air (or a little liquid) from the food is drawn into the machine—-never from the machine to the food. Food is kept in a plastic bag (usually outside the machine) while air is drawn from the bag followed by heat-sealing of the bag opening.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Saba David and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Can you help those not familiar with the machine with the issues you are thinking of? Is it used hot and are there milk/meat issues? Or what are you thinking of? Also when you speak of 'either type' in the title do you mean type of sealer? If yes can you elaborate in the question? Or what other type are you referring to?

Note that there is a lot of space in the question to make it as clear as possible so you can get the best answers

Comment: The most popular brand is FoodSaver. It vacuum seals raw or cooked foods in special plastic bags for extended storage in freezer, refrigerator, or pantry as appropriate. Most commercial frozen foods are packaged this way. Home sealers like FoodSaver use special bags not suitable for liquids. Chamber sealers are much larger and more expensive. Both seal food—usually cold—which remains in the bag and never touches the machine. Examples of sealer operation are readily seen on YouTube or elsewhere on the Internet.